# Can't use fetch api in laravel, redirect login page

Tags: laravel, fetch

I'm trying to use `fetch` api with laravel, but the `request` goes to the login url, not the given url.

for example;

**route**

```
//also this route group has auth and admin middlewares (checks user is authenticated and is admin)
Route::delete("media/delete/{id}", ["as" => "admin.posts.media.delete", "uses" => "AdminController@deletePostMedia"]);
```

**ajax**

```
fetch("../../media/delete/" + id, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: new Headers({
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content
      })
})
```

it gives me the below error:

> DELETE http://commerce.test/login 405 (Method Not Allowed)

as you can see above, the request goes to login url, not given url..

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi @Hasan Tingir,

Could you please provide your laravel routing ?
Seems that you got a redirection because of your routing middleware..

Comment: @WawanBrutalx I updated my question

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the relative path is correct?

Comment: @user3158900 yes I am, xmlhttprequest works fine with same path

Comment: Where did you put that route ? in routes/api.php or routes/web.php ? also can you please share what is inside your AdminController ?

Comment: @WawanBrutalx `routes/admin.php` (in custom route file but using web middleware). in the action method there is just -> `Media::find($id)->delete()` code.

Comment: @HasanTıngır seems that you may have an authentication middleware on your controller, OR you have using an authentication middlware on your kernel for web route.. maybe you can check it on your controller constructor or your Kernel.php file..

What happen if you try to send that request using POSTMAN maybe, did you get a redirection ? if so, then yes, that might be your issue

Answer (score 0):

Laravel by default includes `axios` for ajax requests and it's very easy to use, have a look [here](https://github.com/axios/axios).

In your example you'd write something like this:

```
axios.delete('/media/delete/' + id)
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response.data);
     })
     .catch(error=> {
         console.log(error);
     });
```